# Why does SelectList no longer support a constructor which takes a list of disabled items?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

In Asp.Net MVC the `SelectList` has a constructor overload of the form:

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    object selectedValue,
    IEnumerable disabledValues)
```

However, in Asp.Net Core MVC, there is no longer a constructor which takes disabled items as a parameter:

```
public SelectList(
        IEnumerable items,
        string dataValueField,
        string dataTextField,
        object selectedValue,
        string dataGroupField)
```

I know that I can write my own `SelectList` and add support for disabled items.
However, I wonder what's the reason behind the decision to leave out support for disabled items and is creating a custom SelectList the preferred workaround?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your question. Do you want to have support for passing in a separate list of items which by default will have its SelectListItem's disabled property set to true?

Comment: @DSF: Yes exactly, I wonder why the SelectList does not have such an option to pass in a separate list which will set the SelectedListItem disabled property. I currently created a custom SelectList for that behaviour but I like to know if there is a reason that this feature is missing from the shipped SelectList class.

Comment: You have a valid point. It used to be supported: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList

Comment: I have proposed an edit to your question which asks the question of why the constructor has no longer got support for disabled items. I think it will attract more attention this way and hopefully get you an answer.

Comment: The docs aren't even complete so my guess is it's not finished

Comment: You would need to ask the MVC team why they chose to remove it